# Removing a glitch on a bootstrap sticky navbar when content reaches top

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

With reference to this very useful Bootstrap sticky bar:

http://www.bootply.com/69848

I have noticed that there is a glitch when the nav-bar has reached the top. If you scroll it very slowly, just after the nav-bar reaches the top you will see the content jump behind the nav-bar. I am trying to find out how it is happening but I am having little luck. If I put some padding on the body then the nav-bar jumps when it reaches the top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The glitch happens when `affix` class is added to the `nav` bar. It sets the `top` property to `0`. One way to get away from it is to add a small piece of code to the JS file like this:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
   if ($("#nav").hasClass("affix")) {
       $(".contents").css({top:80});
   } else {
       $(".contents").css({top:0});
   }
});
```

When `affix` class added, `80px`is added to the top property of the `contents` class (which I added to refer to those texts). When `affix` is removed, we go back to `top:0`.

Check out a working example [**HERE**](http://www.bootply.com/hHwJm0LA8e)

Comment: I have +1 because it works on that bootply page. I am baffled as to why I cannot get it to work on my own design. I am using another solution now for the moment but I will maybe come back to this. I did try it in every single possible place on the content structure (by changing ".content").

Comment: Did you notice that I added ".contents" class to the div element right before "<h2>Content</h2>"? Did you do the same thing? You might also need to change "top:80" based on the sizes of your design

Comment: Yes, I located where you had put the .contents in the design. It could possibly be related to the jumbotron at the top of the page. I tried it in there as well though. I do appreciate what you have done and because it has actually worked on that page it is the answer to the question. I will give it correct answer.